# Building 30 day alarm

Tags: java, android, datetime

I'm building an alarm set to reoccur every 30 days.  I was wondering if I could get a few extra sets of eyes to look things over and see if you can notice anything I may have done wrong.  Any/all input is greatly appreciated!

**SOURCE:**

```
public class WifiMonitor extends Activity {

    Button sendButton;

    EditText msgTextField;

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView infoView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.traffic_info);

        double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
        totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
        totalBytes /= 1000000;
        mobileBytes /= 1000000;

        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
        String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
        String info = String.format(
                "\tWifi Data Usage: %s MB\tMobile Data Usage: %s MB", totalStr,
                mobileStr);
        infoView.setText(info);

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("7862611848", null, info, null, null);

        String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent Aintent = new Intent("REFRESH_THIS");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Aintent, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

        // reschedule to check again tomorrow
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(WifiMonitor.this, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent restartServiceIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                WifiMonitor.this, 0, serviceIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        // cancel previous alarm
        alarms.cancel(restartServiceIntent);

        // schedule alarm for today + 1 day
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        // schedule the alarm
        alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                restartServiceIntent);

    }
}
```

**ALARM:**

```
public class Alarm extends Service {

    // compat to support older devices
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        onStartCommand(intent, 0, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // check to ensure everything is functioning

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "WiFi Usage Sent", 2000);
        toast.show();

        // send SMS
        String sms = "";
        sms += ("\tWifi Data Usage: "
                + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                        .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()))
                / 1000000 + " MB");

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("7862611848", null, sms, null, null);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason to avoid using cron and a shell script?

Comment: It's an Android app (which I probably should have mentioned) and I'm looking for the simplest solution. Android doesnt use cron, does it?

Comment: Looks like you do have to use the AlarmManager. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Thought so... 

I've started 2 threads regarding the different issues/questions I'm having regarding this (but no working solutions thus far)  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151775/issues-implementing-monthly-repeating-alarms


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155371/starting-a-future-alarm-based-on-todays-date

Comment: please notice [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14376470/1056359) of mine regarding this issue

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Android, so just some generic note:

1. ```
   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 0);
   ```

   What is this line supposed to do? [Javadoc of `DAY_OF_WEEK`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) says the following:

   > Field number for get and set indicating the day of the week. This field takes 
   >   values `SUNDAY`, `MONDAY`, `TUESDAY`, `WEDNESDAY`, `THURSDAY`, `FRIDAY`, and `SATURDAY`.

   Unfortunately, none of the mentioned constants has `0` as [value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY). (`SUNDAY` = 1, `MONDAY` = 2. ..., `FRIDAY` = 6) You should use on the constants above here for better clarity.
2. I'd move the `Calendar` creation and and modification to a named method where the name explains the purpose of the method. It would be easier just reading the name of the method to figure out what contains the created `Calendar` instance than reading through the calls of setter methods.
3. The `alarm` variable is unused. Remove it.
4. `(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)` is duplicated in the code. You could use the same object and call it twice or create a `getAlarmManager()` method which does the casting too to remove the duplication.
5. ```
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   ```

   Could be simply

   ```
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   ```

   It's the same.